# Can't find "Result Comparison" dialog in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse, junit5

The page below (scroll down to Assertions subheading) refers to a Results Comparison dialog for comparing expected and actual output from a JUnit 5 test. I can't find it. Can someone point me? In the Failure Trace view, there is a "Compare Actual with Expected Test Result" button, but it is grayed out.

https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/october/article5.php

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse Oxygen **4.7.1a**, when executing the following test, I simply double-click on the first line in the *Failure Trace* panel in the *JUnit* view, and the *Result Comparison* window opens.

```java
@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
void groupedAssertions() {
    org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertAll(
        () -> org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals("Johnny", "John"),
        () -> org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals("Dep", "Doe")
    );
}
```

Comment: I (re) tried that and still didn't work. Am using 4.7.1a, but workspace was originally created by Neon. Created a new workspace and it works now!